# Validate page when clicking back

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, security, postback

I am working in an MVC project and I have validation on the page which is called on the "Index" page. The problem I am having is that when I logout of the page and click the "Back" button on the browser, it will take me to the previous page without calling any code.

I know I am validated because as soon as I try to change the page it signs me out, however I am trying to call code when I visit a page from the back button. I read a postback might solve the problem but unsure. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show your logout action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button can have different behaviours based on which browser used.

Often, the browser would show a cached version of the last page, and therefore no request is sent to the server, and no code is executed on the server.

Because no code is executed on the server, this is relatively harmless.

Unless the page is showing some confidential information. In which case, some JavaScript code could send an Ajax request to the server to see if the user is logged in. If not, redirect to the login page.